# Hibernate cache issue with one-to-many/many-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa

I'm using hibernate/JPA with the following entities

```
Class User {
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
   private List<UserAcl> acl;

   ...
}
```

and

```
Class UserAcl {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;

   public void setUser(User user) {
      this.user = user;
   }

   ...
}
```

When I trying to add a new `UserAcl` by execution the following code:

```
UserAcl userAcl = new UserAcl();
userAcl.setUser(user);

em.persist(userAcl);
```

**And a second later (in other transaction) I try to retrieve the previous `User` and when I read `UserAcl` I didn't see the new entry.**

But if I:

- Wait a minute
- Disable cache

or refresh `User` just after persist `UserAcl`:

```
em.persist(userAcl);
em.refresh(user);
```

It works.

But refreshing `User` is a bit tricky. The other solution I found, except disable caching, it's to tune `setUser` method to

```
public void setUser(User user) {
   user.getAcl().add(this);
   this.user = user;
}
```

**But it's the best solution? There is no other way to Hibernate to manage this without changing my setter?**

PS: I tried without `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` or other `cascade` strategy without success.